# Will I get performance benefit if I define index on non primary key in DB2

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, database-performance, sqlperformance

Data for a page in my application is loaded from several tables by joining them on the primary keys. Few tables are joined on non primary keys. Apart from this there are lots of conditions in the where clause on the non primary keys. 
**So defining indexes on the non primary key columns used in where clause will have a performance benefit ?** 
Although the non primary key columns values are not unique but most of the values are **repetitive**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your rather vague question is "yes".  One of the main purposes of indexes is to improve performance of comparisons in `where` clauses.

There are many situations where indexes will not help; but for simple comparison operations, they should speed the operations.

Comment: Thanks!  how do you want me to make my question clearer. Yes most of the comparisons are "=" type comparison. There is just 1 ">" comparison but that is on an indexed column